# Is a transitive group more likely to be soluble if its degree has more prime divisors?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, solvable-groups

There is some empirical evidence that the probability that a permutation group of a given degree is soluble increases with the number of prime divisors of the degree. (Primes are counted with multiplicity so, for instance, $12$ has $3$ prime divisors.) I've tabulated the average proportion of soluble groups of degree $d$, for $5\leq d\leq 47$ (groups of degree less than $5$ are all soluble) according to the number $\Omega(d)$ of prime divisors of $d$.

| $\Omega(d)$ | Average Proportion |
| --- | --- |
| $1$ | $0.66623$ |
| $2$ | $0.65839$ |
| $3$ | $0.78775$ |
| $4$ | $0.95977$ |
| $5$ | $0.99962$ |

This suggests that a transitive group is more likely to be soluble if its degree has more prime divisors.  In fact, it appears from this data that the likelihood that a transitive group of a given degree is soluble tends to $1$ as the number of prime divisors of that degree tends to $\infty$.  (Granted, the only available degree with $5$ prime divisors is $32$; it would be nice to know the proportion for degree $48$.)

**Question.**  Is this known to be true in general and, if so, is it understood why this would be the case?

**Added (2022-05-08):** With the data kindly provided by @DerekHolt, the average proportion for $\Omega(d)=$ changes very slightly to be $0.99956$.

**Added (2022-05-15):** Below is a plot of the proportions of soluble groups of each prime degree $p$ in the range $5\leq p\leq 4093$. A comment of @verret prompted me to take a second look at this data.

[image: Proportions of Soluble Groups of Prime Degree]

**Added (2022-05-16):** Plotting the average proportions of soluble groups of prime degrees $p$ in the range $5\leq p\leq 4093$, as suggested by @verret, yields the following plot. This seems to mostly confirm the behaviour predicted by @verret, though it is not clear that the limit is $1$.  With the available data, the limit appears to approach something around $0.85$; perhaps the limit would reach $1$ eventually, but it is not clear from the data at hand.

[image: Average proportions of soluble groups of prime degrees]

Comment: I would guess that the proportion of transitive groups $G$ of degree $n$ for which $n$ is a power of $2$ and $G$ is a $2$-group approaches $1$ as $n \to \infty$, which would imply your conjecture, but that is probably very hard to prove. (Everyone believes that almost all finite groups are $2$-groups, but it has not been proved.)

Comment: I have started doing the calculation for degree $48$, but it has only done about $10\%$ of the $195826352$ groups, so it will take a couple of days to complete. Of the first $19500000$ groups, $19494301$ are solvable, which is $0.9997\%$.

Comment: @DerekHolt  Thank you for undertaking the degree $48$ calculation.  I would have done so myself, but I do not have access to Magma.

Comment: I think it's quite likely that for fixed $\Omega(d)$, the proportion goes to $1$ anyway. The case when $d$ is a prime is very well-understood. You can calculate the proportion up to 4000 or so using the library of primitive groups, but really, you could go up to the millions using known results and some basic number theory. It's even possible that known number theory is enough to prove that it goes to 1. (Of course, that doesn't answer the OP question, but since the proportion seems to increase with $\Omega(d)$, that might be some kind of evidence...)

Comment: OK, $195729463$ of the $195826352$, which is $0.999505$ of the transitive groups of degree $48$ are solvable. This is slightly less than the proportion for degree $32$, but I would expect the proportion to be highest for degrees a power of $2$, when a very high proportion of the groups are $2$-groups.

Comment: Thanks very much @DerekHolt for the additional data for degree $48$.

Comment: @verret I am grateful for your comment.  Unfortunately, I have not been able to understand the connection you are making with calculations using primitive groups.  Are you saying that we can somehow deduce the proportion of soluble groups among transitive groups for fixed $\Omega(d)$ from the corresponding proportions of soluble primitive groups of the same degrees? I have reviewed my books this past week, but have not been able to see how to make that connection.

Comment: @James A transitive group of prime degree is primitive. So, for this case, you can check in the library of primitive groups to get data, and this goes much further. Moreover, these groups (of prime degree) are very well understood and it's essentially a number theory problem, so you could go even further collecting data using that theory, or even possibly calculate the actual limit.

Comment: @verret Thanks very much for the clarification.  I had misunderstood, thinking you were suggesting a connection also for composite degrees $d$, for fixed $\Omega(d) > 1$.  It is clear now that your comment addresses groups of prime degree.  I do happen to have that data handy and the proportions bounce around a lot more, so it is less clear that the proportions of soluble groups of prime degree are tending to $1$ as the degree increases.  I will need to look more closely at the data to get a better feel for that case.

Comment: @James how far did you check?

Comment: @verret I checked the prime degrees $p$ in the range $5\leq p\leq 4093$.  There are $562$ such prime degrees, too many for a table to be helpful; instead, I have added a point plot that illustrates the distribution of proportions of soluble groups of those degrees.  The largest proportion, about $0.96$ occurs  for degree $p = 2521$ and $p = 3361$.  These two are also the primes $p$ in that range for which the number of divisors of $p - 1$ is largest, so we get a lot of $\operatorname{AGL}(1,p)$ subgroups for those values of $p$  (Continued ...)

Comment: @verret  Also, the mean proportion of soluble groups of prime degree $p$ in that range $5\leq p\leq 4093$ is about $0.83442$.

Comment: @James, right, there will always be 2 insoluble groups ($A_p$ and $S_p)$ and number of divisors of $p-1$ soluble ones (for subgroups of $AGL(1,p)$) for "most" values of $p$, these will be all. The exceptions are well-understood.

Comment: But, in any case, I thought you were interested in the summatory function, that is the total as we range from 1 to d. While the number for any particular $d$ might fluctuate, I expect if you take the sum, the proportion might actually converge... Did you try plotting that? Anyway, I would expect the average number of divisors of $p-1$ to go to infinity, and the exceptional cases not to matter too much, so the proportion should go to 1. I would have to think whether this could actually be proven. (And probably ask a number theorist for help!)